# How to make a Google Analytics code added with script on other domain work?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, cross-domain

I have a domain, lets call it myhost.com and i have a script addGAcode.js on myhost.com. The code contains function includeGA() that calls the standard GA code for a account set for my client domain. It looks like this:

```
function includeGA() {   
var _gaq = _gaq || [];  
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-432432432-43']);  
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);   })(); 
}

includeGA();
```

Lets call this domain groceryinbelfast.com.

Now i add to meta of groceryofbelfast script tag to include the myhost.com/addGAcode.js. Unfortunately GA does not work. The GA code is loaded properly but i suppose because it's located on other domain that the domain groceryofbelfast it cannot set cookies on groceryofbelfast domain that are necessary for statistics to work.

The point of my concept is to have GA script on my server so that when Google will change something in it or i will want to make some adjustments to it i dont need to call every time the webmaster of my client to make appropriate changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most people load the GA script directly from Google's CDN.  Why are you hosting it yourself and then facing these problems?

Comment: No i  dont host it. I only host the code to include the GA from googl CDN. I've added the code of includeGA in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I think the better question is why are you doing it in a non standard way?

Comment: @Petah I dont want to call the webmaster of every client when Google will change the statistics code or i will want to add more parameters etc.

Comment: @tomaszs Google doesn't change it without still supporting the older versions. Also if you want more parameters you will need to modify the source of the clients site anyway, no?

Comment: @Petah Well not. Because i can do all changes from my script, for example add parameter to measure time, or to bind to events and track them in statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `includeGA()` function probably won't work because `_gaq` needs to be declared as a global variable, not a local variable inside your `includeGA()` function.

You can fix that particular issue by changing to this:

```
function includeGA() {   
    window._gaq = window._gaq || [];  
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-432432432-43']);  
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
}
```

Comment: It's kind of funny that I figured this out.  I never did understand your question, but I did spot an error in the code you included so I posted about that.  I guess that shows the advantage to always posted the relevant code!

Comment: natural gift :) yes, i thought the same, without the code i would not get your help